How to concatenate T-SQL script with a wildcard and to be more dynamic?
I have bottom T-SQL Script:
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [WH_BEE] FROM  
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_1.bak',  
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_2.bak',  
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_3.bak',  
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_4.bak',  
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_5.bak', 
DISK = N'F:\NH\WH_BEE_20240819_6.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, 
MOVE N'WH_Data1' TO N'F:\data\WH_BEE.MDF',  
MOVE N'WH_Data2' TO N'F:\data\WH_BEE_1.NDF',  
MOVE N'WH_Log' TO N'G:\log\WH_BEE.LDF',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

What I am trying to do is instead of indicating individual date like '20240819', how do I modify these portions (using a wildcard) so that it is more like:
DISK = N'F:\NM\WH_BEE_' + * + '_1.bak'
DISK = N'F:\NM\WH_BEE_' + * + '_2.bak'
DISK = N'F:\NM\WH_BEE_' + * + '_3.bak'
DISK = N'F:\NM\WH_BEE_' + * + '_4.bak'
DISK = N'F:\NM\WH_BEE_' + * + '_5.bak'
DISK = N'F:\NM\WH_BEE_' + * + '_6.bak'

Also, if possibly having more than just 6 files, can I make this T-SQL more dynamic (instead of having strictly 6, just in case it can go up to 7..)?

What exact logic do you need, are the bak files always sequentially numbered from 1? Do you need today's date always or do you need to pass in a parameter? Have you considered using Powershell and DbaTools Restore-DbaDatabase which does most of this for you https://docs.dbatools.io/Restore-DbaDatabase.html

@Charlieface Today's date is always required. I prefer to stay within T-SQL rather than other language because this script is almost ready to use. I came to this far after many trials using other T-SQL sample.  Thank you.

@Charlieface Sorry. I am still getting error (as shown on the top).

@Charlieface It worked!! I actually had to modify little bit on how date should display. I updated the post with how I modified yours. Thank you so much for last two-three days! So, is max 6 pretty much static limit?

Set that second line @maxInputFiles to whatever number you want.

@Charlieface Yea, but I have to specify the correct number as I see the change in the future possibly. correct? I cannot just put 10, and 6 might work..

No the idea is you put in the number matching the number of files you have. This is why Powershell is much better: it can actually search for files based on wildcards etc, and do other transformations automatically.

@Charlieface Actually, I am going to try the Powershell script that you shared. It appears that I need to install dbatools first.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

@DaleK Sorry. I will do so from now. Thank you. I deleted the image of code.

You can build it dynamically using STRING_AGG with a parameter to say how many files.
On SQL 2022 and Azure you can just use GENERATE_SERIES to get multiple rows. Otherwise use a VALUES clause and some cross-joins. There are other options to generate multiple rows from nothing.
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @maxInputFiles BIGINT = 6;

WITH L1 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n(n)
),
L2 AS (
    SELECT 1 n
    FROM L1 AS a, L1 AS b
)
SELECT @sql = N'
RESTORE DATABASE [WH_BEE]
FROM ' +
  STRING_AGG(
    CONCAT('
DISK = N''F:\NH\WH_BEE_',
      CONVERT(nvarchar(10), GETDATE(), 110),
      '_',
      g.value,
      '.bak'''
    ),
    ', '
  ) + N'
WITH FILE = 1, 
MOVE N''WH_Data1'' TO N''F:\data\WH_BEE.MDF'',  
MOVE N''WH_Data2'' TO N''F:\data\WH_BEE_1.NDF'',  
MOVE N''WH_Log'' TO N''G:\log\WH_BEE.LDF'', STATS = 5;
'
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@maxInputFiles)
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS value
    FROM L2
) AS g;

PRINT @sql;    -- your friend

EXEC master.sys.sp_executesql @sql;

Honestly you should probably just use Powershell and the DbaTools module. This will automatically get all the correct files and generate the correct statement. For example
Get-ChildItem "F:\NH\WH_BEE_$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd")_*.bak" | `
Restore-DbaDatabase `
    -SqlInstance instanceName `
    -Database DbName `
    -FileMapping @{
       "WH_Data1" = "F:\data\WH_BEE.MDF";
       "WH_Data2" = "F:\data\WH_BEE_1.NDF";
       "WH_Log" = "G:\log\WH_BEE.LDF"
    };


@Charleface I tried your T-SQL and got this error (updated on the post (top)). Also, do I have to first have a database created first and run this script?

Sorry missed a line. Note that GENERATE_SERIES is only supported in SQL20222 and Azure, otherwise we can change that to a cross-join tally. No, RESTORE DATABASE specifically requires the database does not exist, otherwise you need to use the , REPLACE option

Sorry. I am not sure how to fix the error. I am not sure how to change to "cross-join tally". I am using SQL 2019. I posted the error message on the top.

I was trying your ps script, and got an error. I asked on this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78903480/powershell-error-message-failure-the-network-path-was-not-found). Do you have any clue by chance?

I am trying to revisit this. On the top code, how do I for "SqlIntance name" What is an example?

You want YourMachineName or YourMachineName,PortNumber or YourMachineName\InstanceName. So something like server1.contoso.com\SQLEXPRESS. I said this on your other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78903480/powershell-error-message-failure-the-network-path-was-not-found#comment139127115_78903480
