Powershell error message: Failure | The network path was not found
I am relatively new to Powershell, and I got a script to use to restore database in SQL Server 2019.
I was running this bottom Powershell script on my new VM, and got bottom error message.
This is Powershell script that I was running:
Get-ChildItem "F:\NH\WH_BEE_$(Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd")_*.bak" | `
Restore-DbaDatabase `
    -SqlInstance instanceName `
    -Database WH_BEE `
    -FileMapping @{
       "WH_Data1" = "F:\data\WH_BEE.MDF";
       "WH_Data2" = "F:\data\WH_BEE_1.NDF";
       "WH_Log" = "G:\log\WH_BEE.LDF"
    };

This is error message:
WARNING: [20:29:39][Restore-DbaDatabase] Failure | The network path was not found

I recently installed dbatools on this VM.
Am I missing anything on the script?
Or installation probably not done correctly?
To install dbatools, I just typed bottom on WindowsPowerShell as an Administrator.
 Install-Module dbatools

Update (8/24/2024):


I suspect you are not able to access the file location. If you open File Explorer and go to "F:\NH", do you see a WH_BEE_20240822_*.bak file there?

@DBADon Yes, I am able to. I tried later by moving all folders' locations to "C:\Users\MyName..", but still having the same issue.

Does the SQL Server Service Account have access to those paths though? It doesn't matter if you do, the thing that matters is if SQL Server does (which for the default account is very limited). If F: is actually a network drive (I hope not as that's where you're restoring to), then that drive will not exist for the Service Account; mapped drives are specific to users. Use the UNC path and, again, ensure the Service Account has access to that path.

What did you put for instancename? Also this script should be executed on the server, not on the client machine.

@ThomA Sorry. I need some guidance. Do I use "NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT" as user? Which drive is safest to use? "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL"? Can you give me some example of UNC path?

The SQL Server Agent Account is the Service Account for the SQL Server Agent, @Java, not the data engine. You need to give permission to the SQL Server (Data Engine) Service Account. That will be whatever you set that to be when you installed/configured SQL Server.

@ThomA  "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER"?

What does your configuration manager tell you, @Java..? I can't tell you what you set your configuration to.

@ThomA I added an image on the post (top) after I went to Services.msc.

@Charlieface Do I have to replace where it says "instancename" with something else? Also, when I ran this Powershell from me, I got the error as indicated on the post. But, when I placed this inside SQL Server Agent and ran it, I got no error, but no result (database was not created).

Yes I thought that was obvious. It would be the name of your instance, eg .\SQLEXPRESS or YourServerMachineName.yourdomain.com,10433 with a fixed port number. From the looks of your screenshot it's a default instance, so just . if accessing on the same machine, or just YourServerMachineName.yourdomain.com from another machine. Are you able to use any other DbaTools script to connect, such as Connect-DbaInstance or Find-DbaInstance
